# how to write to multiple files one after another in qt?

Tags: c++

my program needs to write to multiple files one after the other stored in folder... i hav used foreach statement to open a files ... bt when i am trying to write to it... its nt working...
my code for writing files is..

```
QString path = ui->pathBox->text();
QDir mydir(path);
QStringList filter("*.txt");
foreach (QString filename,mydir.entryList(filter,QDir::Files))
{
    QFile ofil(filename);
    if(!ofil.open(QIODevice::Append | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        qDebug() << "The file could not opened";
        return;
    }
    QTextStream ostream(&ofil);
    QString name = ui->nameBox->text();
    ostream << name;

    ofil.flush();
    ofil.close();
}
```

plz tell me the correct way to write it????

Comment: What do you mean by `its not working`, please clarify

Comment: i mean to say that, no text is being written to file....

Comment: the file remains as it is after the operation...

Comment: Have you debuged it? Are you sure the loop-body is executed? Are you sure the filename is right? Are you sure that `name` is not empty? Please check

Comment: yes i do... i have also checked for filename.... by printing the filename... n my all file names are printing on console properly... means loop body is ok..

Comment: the problem is that if am writing to single file... is ok... but if m trying to write to multiple files in loop no output.. remains as it is...